# Find the area of the square in that figure.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles, area

[image]

For the above figure,

- Figure is symmetric with respect to both $AC$ & $BD$
- $ADC,ABC,DFBE$ are circle or part of circle
- The outer quadrilateral is a square
- Extended upper sides touch extended arch of $ADC$
- Extended lower sides touch extended arch of $ABC$
- $AC=6$ $\mathrm{cm}$, $BD=2$ $\mathrm{cm}$

Find green, black and white colored areas.

I have found the green and the black area using area of circle & trigonometry. Could you please tell me how can I find the side length of the square so that I can find the area of that square?

Comment: @user Not necessarily a full circle, but arcs $ADF$ and $ABC$ must subtend a central angle $\ge90°$.

Comment: On reading more carefully, *extended* arcs are mentioned, hence the construction can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT.

The line connecting the center of circle $ADC$ with a tangency point must form an angle of $45°$ with line $BD$.

[image]

Comment: `@Aretino`, got it! But the figure that OP has provided is misleading.